# Wheelnav: Is there a way to reset or invoke the onhover effect for items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wheelnav.js

To further elaborate on the title. I've noticed that when you have a spinning wheel, and select an item the wheel will as expected spin around to showcase the selected item. However.. if you leave your mouse where it is when you pressed an item, the new item that moves underneath the mouse will not be highlighted using the 'onhover' method. To force the hover effects on the item underneath the mouse you either have to move the mouse to the title of the item, or move away from the item and then move the mouse back onto the item to once again have the onhover effects displayed. This is an issue that is present on the examples on the homepage as well incase you want to try it out.
Is there any way to call the onhover method manually for the item underneath the mouse?
Here's a [link](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/examples.html) to try it out.
The same issue applied when you invoke spreadWheel() and the cursor is at the newly activated wheels position. The items wont highlight until you move the mouse around, on the title or re-enter the div.

On the first image the mouse is hovering over the item 'CSS'. When I select the item, another item moves in during the spin, and 'SVG' is now placed under the mouse. The new item is not highlighted until the cursor moves over the title or re-enters the slice.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design so there is no built-in way to reset this.

If you want to modify the source code look around [here](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.1/js/source/wheelnav.navItem.js#L278).